# Setting up a Spline chart size and the image size inside the chart flexible with the browser window size

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, devexpress

I have created a Spline chart using DevExpress controls. I want the full chart to make flexible using JS and JQuery. The problem is if I am setting up the size of the chart using JQuery and css, like using below code, the image is getting blur.

```
$('#myChart_IMG').css('height', $(window).height()).css('width', $(window).width());
```

And if I am setting the chart size using devexpress code for sizing, then it is not becoming flexible. Like the below code.

```
settings.Width = 1366;
settings.Height = 763;
```

What can be the solution? Below is my full code.

```
<style type="text/css">
    body, html {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
</style>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myChart_IMG').css('height', $(window).height()).css('width', $(window).width());
    })
</script>
@Html.DevExpress().Chart(settings =>
{
    settings.Name = "myChart";
    settings.Width = 1366;
    settings.Height = 763;
    Series chartSeries1 = new Series("My Data", DevExpress.XtraCharts.ViewType.Spline);
    chartSeries1.ArgumentDataMember = "X";
    chartSeries1.ValueDataMembers[0] = "Y";
    Series chartSeries2 = new Series("My Chart", DevExpress.XtraCharts.ViewType.Spline);
    chartSeries2.ArgumentDataMember = "X";
    chartSeries2.ValueDataMembers[0] = "Z";
    settings.Series.Add(chartSeries2);
    settings.Series.Add(chartSeries1);
}).Bind(Model).GetHtml()
```

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET MVC? Because I have a solution for you, only it's in ASP.NET WebForms.

Comment: @BishopBarber,yes I am using Mvc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is normal. You are enlarging the image thanks to CSS, thus your image will become blurry. Normally, with `chart.SetWidth` and `chart.SetHeight` on the ClientSide, you should be able to resize the chart. Unfortunately, DevExpress does not provide the possibility to do so without sending a callback to the server, because that's where the image is generated. So, if you want to make your chart flexible with the browser window size when the document has been loaded, you must perform a callback on the chart and resize the chart on the server side.

You said you're using ASP.NET MVC, but I unfortunately only am somewhat experienced with ASP.NET WebForms. Although, I'm pretty sure the solution's idea can be easily implemented in MVC:

- Add two hidden fields in your view, one that would contain the window width and one that would contain the height
- When the document has been loaded, set the hidden fields values according to the window's dimensions and perform a callback on the chart:

  ```
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#hiddenFieldWidth').val($(window).width());
      $('#hiddenFieldHeight').val($(window).height());
      myChart.PerformCallback();
  })
  ```
- Lastly, change the chart's size in the appropriate controller action thanks to the hidden fields values.

I hope you'll be able to find how to do all of this in ASP.NET MVC.